# What is a good practice to combine your classes

Tags: java, android

Not to keep all my classes in a single src -> 'package_name' folder I'm creating different sub-packages in order to separate my classes by groups like - utilities, models, activities themselves, etc. I'm not sure if it is a good practice and people do the same in real projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely standard practice to separate your classes into packages.  It's good to establish a convention for how they are separated, to make it easier to find things later.  Two common approaches:

1. Put things into packages based on what they are: model, service, data access (DAO), etc.
2. Put things into packages based on what function they support (for example, java.io, java.security, etc.

I've used both and keep coming back to the former because it's less subjective (it's always clear whether a class is a model or a service, but not always clear whether it supports one function or another function).

Answer (score 1):

Doing it by class type the way you describe is one way that I've seen in real projects.  I don't care for it as much as I used to because when I need to make a change or add a feature I tend to need to have several packages expanded in my IDE.  I prefer (when I have the choice) to group classes by feature instead.  That way I know where to look for all classes that support that feature.

Answer (score 1):

The convention I prefer is to group classes first by module, then by functionality.  For example, you could have the following structure:

```
com.example.modulea - modulea specific code that doesn't have any real need of a different package
com.example.modulea.dao - data access for module a
com.example.modulea.print - printing for module a
```

...

```
com.example.moduleb - moduleb specific code that doesn't have any real need of a different package
com.example.moduleb.dao - data access for module b
com.example.moduleb.print - printing for module b
```

In this fashion, code is clearer by package.

In the other style, of grouping by pure functionality, the package size tends to be quite large.  If your project contains 15 modules, and each module has one or more elements per package, that's at least 15 classes per package.  I much prefer clearly separated packages than packages that simply group things because "oh here are some printing utilities that are used for every module but only one module actually uses one of them from this package" - it just gets confusing.