# Merge all Android project classes in one file with the Android Studio

Tags: android, class, android-studio

I have maybe strange question, but would be appreciate if someone helps.

I need to merge all the code from classes ( which are part of the packages ) in one text or class file for Android project in Android Studio.

So I have for example such a structure

[image]

And I need to merge the code from `NewAlbumDialog`, `MenuAdapter`, `MenuItem` etc classes in one big file.

Maybe somebody know how can I do it with the Android Studio.

Would be appreciate your help.

Comment: You could've opened up a text editing software, copied and pasted each individual file's contents to that and saved by the same time you finished typing this question. :)

Comment: @JanithaR, no. Currently there are 405 views of the question, so many people faced this problem. The author asked, and they saw there were no automatic solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a tool for this. Just use a text editor.

However be aware that a Java file is not valid as soon as it includes more than one public class - see [Multiple classes in single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132729/multiple-classes-in-single-file)