# ApkTool splits java files in to multiple files

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali, apktool

Im using ApkTool to dessasemble DEX files from an APK to recover smali code. I have noticed that the `.java` file has been splitted in different files.

For example:

- MainActivity.java -> MainActivity.smali, MainActivity$1.smali
- FirstFragment.java -> FirstFragment.smali, FirstFragment$1.smali, FirstFragment$2.smali

Is there a reason for why this happens?

I have an additional question in relation to that: why do the first lines of those files have different content if they reference the same file? They both reference the source "MainActivity.java" but have different classes.

MainActivity$1.smali

```
.class Lcom/example/testapp/MainActivity$1;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "MainActivity.java"
```

MainActivity.smali

```
.class public Lcom/example/testapp/MainActivity;
.super Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity;
.source "MainActivity.java"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.smali` file is created for a single Java class. A `.java` file can include several Java classes either explicitly, or implicitly. Explicitly - can be for an inner class; implicitly - e.g. to create a Thread (with an anonymous class). Consider:

```java
package Abc;

class Foo {
  class Bar {}
}
```

Internally, fully resolved class names would be `Abc/Foo` and `Abc/Foo$Bar`. Note the `$` sign that separates inner class name. It can go on, like `Abc/Foo$Bar$Func`. Anonymous classes simply get numbers for names, like `Abc/Foo$1` and `Abc/Foo$1$1`.

Now [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and [baksmali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali) behind the scene use the fully resolved class name for a file path and name.

---

(*) Usually, every Java class is put into a file of its own with file name and path matching the package name and self name of that class. This is a convention. Given only one class is public, other can appear in the same file - [Multiple classes in single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132729/multiple-classes-in-single-file).